# Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 upgrade got interrupted

Tags: 14.04, 16.04

Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 upgrade got interrupted due to power failure. Now when I try to upgrade again I am getting the following message:

"Not all upgrades can be installed, run a partial upgrade"

[image]

What should I do to upgrade to 16.04?

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was caused by ***"A previous upgrade which didn't complete"***.

Choosing **Partial Upgrade** installed the 16.04 upgrade for me.